# Error: Could not find or load main class error while loading school.School.server.policy

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi

Error: Could not find or load main class school.School.server.policy
my rmi server giving this error while I run it I am using eclipse

VM argument are these

```
-Djava.security.manager 
-Djava.security.policy=${workspace_loc}/School/server.policy
-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:${workspace_loc}/School/bin/
```

server code is

```
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;


public class SchoolSever { 
    public static void main (String[] args){
    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null){
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    }
    try{
        String name = "School";
        SchoolInterfaceImpl sii = new SchoolInterfaceImpl();
        SchoolInterface stub =
                (SchoolInterface ) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(sii, 0);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
        registry.rebind(name, stub);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.err.print("Server not running: " );
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

server policy

```
grant {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jpn3.png)

Comment: Clearly something wrong with your non-shown command line. You are supplying the policy file name as though it was a class name.

Comment: server.policy this is my policy file name could you please clearly tell what should i do with it to add it to eclipse class SchoolSever

Comment: @ejb my vm argument -Djava.security.manager 
-Djava.security.policy=${workspace_loc}/School/server.policy
-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:${workspace_loc}/School/bin/              whole work stop due to this error i will be thankful to you if you solve my this problem     "You are supplying the policy file name as though it was a class name" please clearify it so i start my work

Comment: @EJP what more needed to resolve my issue please tell me

Comment: Show your entire command line. There is something wrong with it along the lines I mentioned. And don't post it in an illegible comment. Edit it into your question.

Comment: @EJP this is all my command line argument which i pass in vm argument i could not able to load the image b/c of low reputation but still need help

Comment: @EJP i didn't see the image you see the image this what i pass only in argument